# parse output of script/utils-linux into human-readable form

Tags: unix, gnu-screen

How do I parse the output of script/utils-linux  into human-readable form
or into something I can process with regexps?
There are some binary escape sequences used to display colours etc.

<s>Is there a unix tool to record the text console (e.g. gnu screen) 
in a human-readable form with milliseconds timings ?</s>

ttyrec/ttyplay uses a rather unreadable format I was not able to find 
proper documentation for; the screen function logstamp creates a
somewhat more readable log but is unable to give precise timings, only 
up to a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [script](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) command.

Comment: Thanks!  One more question: it seems to use escape sequences/codes, how do I know what these mean? Is there some standard?

Comment: @John, those are probably coming from GNU Screen, not `script`  From the `script` man page, "Certain interactive commands, such as vi(1), create garbage in the typescript file. Script works best with commands that do not manipulate the screen"

Answer (score 1):

you can easily parese ttyrec with something like that: https://github.com/antono/shelr/blob/master/lib/shelr/ttyrec.rb

If you want to just share your terminal there is http://shelr.tv/ with corresponding utility: https://github.com/antono/shelr

If you want strip escape sequences you can do it with following command:

sed -r "s/\x1B[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"